# How to mark a jasmine test incomplete?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

In Jasmine 2.0 I can use `xit` instead of `it` to make jasmine skip the test. [Disabling suites](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Disabling_Suites)

I am likely to forget these tests since they don't appear in the result. So I was hoping to mark these tests as incomplete, this should warn me to look at it at some point.

Is it possible to mark them as disabled/incomplete so that they appear in the results as such?

Comment: They do appear in the result. I just ran my tests and I can see them marked differently in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `--verbose` output by jasmine-node skipped tests `xit`/`xdescribe` won't appear unless the feature is built.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much linked the answer in your question already. Everything, that you ask for is described [here](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Disabling_Suites).

### Example

```
  xdescribe('Disabled suits', function() {
    it('test one', function() {
    });

    it('test two', function() {
    });

    it('test three', function() {
    });

    it('test four', function() {
    });
  });

  describe('Disabled suits tests', function() {
    it('Enabled test one', function() {
    });

    it('Enabled test two', function() {
    });

    xit('Disabled test one', function() {
    });

    xit('Disabled test two', function() {
    });
  });
```

Exception with first example is that it isn't displayed at all in the output. Not sure why. Maybe some option must be passed during execution, but second test suite, disabled/pending tests are marked differently in output.

Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: I don't get the disabled output in jasmine, it must be an output specific to karma